# Error when i update data from dropdown in FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, dart

This widget creates dropdownmenuitems after making a request to a url when user selected one value in dropdown A, but when user change the value of dropdown A, i get error. I tried researching this error and found no helpful answers.

the code is below

```
  FutureBuilder(
            future: listProductsPrice(currentProducts),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    hint: Text("Preço"),
                    value: currentPriceProducts,
                    items: null,
                    onChanged: (selected) {},
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                List<PriceProducts> priceProducts = snapshot.data;
                return _listViewProductsPrice(priceProducts, "Preço");
              }
            }),


  Widget _listViewProductsPrice(List<PriceProducts> priceProducts, title) {
    return Container(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(245, 242, 240, 0.20),
        child: DropdownButton(
          hint: Text(title),
          value: currentPriceProducts,
          items: priceProducts.map((products) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              value: products.value,
              child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                products.value,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
              )),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (selected) {
            // widget.objMobileRecharge.area_code = int.parse(selected);
            print(selected);
            setState(() {
              currentPriceProducts = selected;
            });
          },
        ));
  }
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 560 pos 15: 'items == null || I/flutter (11514): items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) => item.value == I/flutter (11514): value).length == 1': is not true.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DropdownButton` `value` is the value of currently selected `DropdownMenuItem` or can be null if no item has been selected.

This part `items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value == value).length == 1` from the exception means that there is no (or more than one) `DropdownMenuItem` with `value` you set for `DropdownButton` `value` (in this case `value: currentPriceProducts`).

Example:

```
DropdownButton(
  hint: Text("Hint"),
  value: "abc123", // currently selected value - "abc123" or "def456" or null
  items: [
    DropdownMenuItem(
      value: "abc123",
      child: Text("ABC123"),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(
      value: "def456",
      child: Text("DEF456"),
    ),
  ],
  onChanged: (value) {},
)
```

Looks like the problem here is the FutureBuilder. When you select a value, `setState()` is called and widget is rebuilt. This means that FutureBuilder is rebuilt and `listProductsPrice(currentProducts)` is called again and probably returns different values. If these values doesn't contain your selected value, you get this error.

So you could do this: Create stateful widget with your dropdown menu

```
class Dropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<PriceProduct> priceProducts;

  const Dropdown({Key key, this.title, this.priceProducts}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DropdownState createState() => _DropdownState();
}

class _DropdownState extends State<Dropdown> {

  String _selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton(
      hint: Text(widget.title),
      value: _selected,
      items: widget.priceProducts.map((product) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: product.value,
          child: Container(
            child: Text(
              product.value,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _selected = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: listProductPrice(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: DropdownButton(
          hint: Text("Preço"),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Dropdown(title: "Preço", priceProducts: snapshot.data);
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: @Dougsrodrigues i updated my answer. Try to set value in DropdownButton to `currentPriceProducts.value`.

Comment: how? currentPriceProducts is a String

Comment: @Dougsrodrigues Oh, sorry, that was not the issue. I updated my answer once again.